# Strategies for returning the values at the bottom of a hierarchy of classes

Tags: python-2.7, oop, gerrit

I'm working with the `Gerrit REST API`, and have been tasked with regularly parsing all commits ever made and putting them into an `AWS` database for analytics.  To get to the commits, I first need to get a list of all projects, then in those projects get a list of all changes and revisions for each change, and then finally I can use that information to get individual commits.

To solve this problem I created a hierarchy of classes where essentially a `Project` contains 1 to many `Change`'s which contains 1 to many `Commit`'s.  Each `Commit` will have a `write_data` method so I can easily write them out to a flat file to upload to `S3`.  I'm looking for some strategies where I can most efficiently parse through and create a "cascade" effect where I kick off an individual thread for each project, which will in turn populate each change, which will in turn populate a list of commits, and then each thread will return a list that contains the commit objects for easy writing.  Here are the three classes:

```
class Project(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.changes = []

    def add_changes(self, changes_list):
        for change in changes_list:
            self.changes.append(Change(
                project=self.name,
                change_id=change['change_id'],
                _id=change['id'],
                revision_list=change['revisions']
            ))

    def return_results(self, ger_obj, start=0):
        while True:
            endpoint = (r'/changes/?q=project:{project}&o=ALL_REVISIONS&'
                        r'S={num}'.format(
                project=self.name,
                num=start
            ))
            print 'Endpoint: {}'.format(endpoint)
            try:
                changes = ger_obj.get(endpoint)
                self.add_changes(changes_list=changes)
            except HTTPError:
                break
            start += 500
            try:
                if not changes[-1].get('_more_changes'):
                    break
            except IndexError:
                break


class Change(object):
    def __init__(self, project, change_id, _id, revision_list):
        self.project = project
        self.change_id = change_id
        logging.info('Change id is', self.change_id)
        self.id = _id
        self.commits = [Commit(rid, change_id)
                        for rid in revision_list.keys()]

    def _return_commits(self):
        return self.commits


class Commit(object):
    def __init__(self, rev_id, change_id):
        self.rev_id = rev_id
        self.change_id = change_id

    def return_results(self, ger_obj):
        endpoint = (r'/changes/{c_id}/revisions/{r_id}/commit'.format(
            c_id=self.change_id,
            r_id=self.rev_id
        ))
        logging.info('Endpoint: {}'.format(endpoint))
        self.data = ger_obj.get(endpoint)


    def write_data(self, writer):
        self.data['message'].encode('string_escape').replace('|', '[pipe]')
        writer.writerow(self.data)
```

I was thinking that perhaps the best time to aggregate all the commits was to have each `Change` object return it's commits after populating them, then I can just keep adding to them as threads finish.  Or I was toying with the idea of not even storing the `Change`'s in each `Project`, and perhaps returning a generator object from the `add_changes` method instead.  What would be the most efficient and scalable design pattern?